# How to sort values not by rows, but by columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A-store',5,'B-store',4,'C-store',6], \
                   ['B-store',3,'P-store',4,np.nan,np.nan], \
                   ['N-store',20,np.nan,np.nan,'I-store',9], \
                   ['L-store',8,'N-store',2,'A-store',5]],
           columns=['store_1','time_1','store_2','time_2','store_3','time_3'])
```

```
   store_1  time_1  store_2  time_2  store_3  time_3
0  A-store       5  B-store     4.0  C-store     6.0
1  B-store       3  P-store     4.0      NaN     NaN
2  N-store      20      NaN     NaN  I-store     9.0
3  L-store       8  N-store     2.0  A-store     5.0
```

Ex: To get to the A-store it takes 5 minutes.

**How can I sort the set of values (store, time) so that the leftmost set becomes the shortest and right most becomes the longest.** I need to sort set of values over multiple columns. Also, it includes NaN.

Here is ideal output.

```
shorter <----------------------------------->  longer
   store_1  time_1  store_2  time_2  store_3  time_3
0  B-store     4.0  A-store       5  C-store     6.0
1  B-store       3  P-store     4.0      NaN     NaN
2  I-store     9.0  N-store      20      NaN     NaN
3  N-store     2.0  A-store     5.0  L-store       8
```

I could probably pivot or stack, and sort by rows. But, I'm not sure how to do this.

If anyone have any good ideas or codes, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is reshape values with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then sorting per first level and `time` column, create new order by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last reshape back to original:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

df1=df.stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).rename_axis('lvl1').sort_values(['lvl1','time'])
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1), append=True)

df1 = df1.unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1).rename_axis(None)
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   store_1  time_1  store_2  time_2  store_3  time_3
0  B-store     4.0  A-store     5.0  C-store     6.0
1  B-store     3.0  P-store     4.0      NaN     NaN
2  I-store     9.0  N-store    20.0      NaN     NaN
3  N-store     2.0  A-store     5.0  L-store     8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a longer way of doing it. Maybe someone could give you a better approach. But this gives the output that you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator

def func(lst):
    d = ({lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)})
    d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return [val for sublist in d for val in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame([['A-store',5,'B-store',4,'C-store',6], \
                   ['B-store',3,'P-store',4,np.nan,np.nan], \
                   ['N-store',20,np.nan,np.nan,'I-store',9], \
                   ['L-store',8,'N-store',2,'A-store',5]],
           columns=['store_1','time_1','store_2','time_2','store_3','time_3'])

pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.apply(lambda x : func(x),axis=1) columns=['store_1','time_1','store_2','time_2','store_3','time_3'],
```

)

This would return the below as output.

```
    store_1 time_1  store_2 time_2  store_3 time_3
0   B-store 4.0     A-store 5.0     C-store 6.0
1   B-store 3.0     P-store 4.0     NaN     NaN
2   N-store 20.0    NaN     NaN     I-store 9.0
3   N-store 2.0     A-store 5.0     L-store 8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look at yours as well.